# Codeigniter routing question

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a CI application with organized folders.
I have several folders on views, controllers and models.

ie.:
/controllers/frontend/, controllers/backend
/views/frontend, views/backend

... etc ...

So if i want to access the function 'login' on the frontend controller i have to go to: http://localhost/frontend/login/index

What i want is to get rid of the need of typing 'frontend', so if i type http://localhost/login/index, it would be the same as http://localhost/frontend/login/index.

Of course i dont want to add them manually to the routes file, i want it to be recognized automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Try specifying base path in config file as `http://localhost/frontend/`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line 17 in your config.php file in application\config.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

Change above to below:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/frontend/';
```

Comment: Hey PHP_Guy, that actually would work. The problem is: i'm using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] for the base_url, because  i'm expecting url's like http://client_alias.appdomain.com

Comment: I think you need to do a URL rewrite. check Youtube for some tutorials on this.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to change your routing for each controller, but if this is the only one you need to do a specific routing for, you can change the default controller in the Router file inside your application/config folder to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend';
$route['(:any)'] = "frontend/some_secondary_variable";
```

The second line is only if you need to pass variables to the controller, otherwise, omit it.